# Selector that confirms image loaded using Selenium Python API

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am looking for a way to confirm the image has actually loaded. Maybe JavaScript is an option? I am using right now `WebdriverWait` to simply force the wait on all images, then the actual `src`, then I finally run my tests after...

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
...
albums = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".albums .album img")))
        albumslength = len(albums)-1
        while albumslength > 0:
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.album:nth-child('+str(albumslength)+') img[src*="album-foo"]'))))
            albumslength -= 1
...
```

This will at some point confirm "**album-foo**" exists in the `<img src="http://www.album-foo/images/blah.jpg"` of each album in albums. But it does not confirm that the image completed loading into view. I have searched high and low, anyone have a solution?

I am testing on Chrome and Firefox, so no phantom or IE restrictions, if the ideas grow into including JavaScript or related ideas that might have environment restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that experienced with selenium, though I will give this a try.
If you want to check whether an image is loaded, I'd say use a boolean. Set the original value of this boolean let's say 'loaded' to false.

Then just call something like this, making sure it returns true the moment the image has loaded.

```
Boolean loaded = false;

WebDriver driver = new AnyDriverYouWant();
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
}
loaded = (Boolean)js.executeScript("image.onload(function() { return true; });");
```

Comment: let me see if I can convert to Python.

Comment: In Python this should be something like wd = webdrive.anyWebDrive();
loaded = false;

loaded = wd.executeScript("image.onload(function() { return true; });")

Comment: I think it is a bit more than that, `;` do not exist, it might be more like `wd.browser.executeScript()`, and false is False in Python. I am still trying to build this in Python.